# Sync Data From a Service in Directive and on Server

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following

**Service**:

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('UserFactory', function ($http) {
    function profile () {
      return $http.get('/gimme')
        .then(function success (response) {
          return response;
        });
    };    
    var user = {
      profile: profile
    };


    return user;
```

It is used in a controller as follows:

**Controller**

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('HeaderCtrl', function ($scope, UserFactory) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    $scope.user = UserFactory.profile().then(function (response) {
      $scope.user = response.data;
    });

    $scope.change = function () {
       $scope.user.name = 'New Name'
    }
}
```

If I call the `change()` method in a directive which uses `HeaderCtrl`, what is the best way to make sure that that change, which temporarily changes the user.name, actually changes it on my server as well? In other words, how would I trigger the put request (I am assuming some function needs to be called on the Factory, but I am not sure the best way to make sure it is called or where to put the function call in the controller).

Thanks

Comment: Add function for `$http.put()` in your service and call it with `user`. And btw loose assigment `$scope.user = UserFactotory.profile()...` and just leave it after promise has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example extending the code you provided, using free `JSONPlaceholder` API. I think example itself is enough of an answer?

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
  <div>data: {{ vm.todo | json }}</div>
  <div>response: {{ vm.response | json }} </div>
  <hr>
  <button type="button" ng-click="vm.change('my new title')">Change title</button>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function(TodoService) {
  var vm = this;
  var id = 1;

  TodoService.getPost(id).then(function(response) { // Get
    vm.todo = response.data; 
  }); 

  vm.change = function(val) {
    vm.todo.title = val;

    TodoService.putPost(vm.todo).then(function(response) { // Put   
      vm.response = response.status + ' ' + response.statusText;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      vm.response = angular.toJson(error);
    });
  };
});

app.factory('TodoService', function($http) {
  var endpoint = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';
  var todoService = {};

  todoService.getPost = function(id) {
    return $http.get(endpoint + id).then(function(response) {
      return response;
    });
  };

  todoService.putPost = function(todo) {
    return $http.put(endpoint + todo.id, todo).then(function(response) {
      return response;
    });
  };

  return todoService;
});
```

---

[image: imgur]

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/VBvVen